# Secure conduit within walls and through lower stud

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

I have an exterior wall opened up on my house and was thinking about installing a conduit to allow myself some flexibility in the future. Possibly:

- ethernet for security camera
- simple run for 120v outlet
- Wiring for a small solar array (2 or 3 consumer panels)

As this is on an exterior wall, my bottom stud (it's not a stud, but I don't know the right term for the wood on top of the foundation) sits on top of the foundation. I don't want to drill into the foundation. I'm wondering how I properly fit a conduit in the wall, where the hole below will need to be drilled at an angle.

For reference, I had an electrician today extend my car charger in this wall area. In the top picture, you can see the cable coming out, and in the bottom picture, the cable entering (and the guess holes). Can I drill another angled hole and secure the conduit over the hole in the stud, or does the conduit need to extend all the way, unbroken into the house, terminating in a box?

[image]

Comment: You can't put AC power and low voltage in the same conduit.  So lay two. 1/2" conduit will satisfy most needs. EMT has the thinnest wall.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Understood, thanks. Certainly wouldn't double up in the same conduit.

Comment: Notice, too, the fire block putty in the first picture. It's important to have that fire block to help slow the spread of fire from floor to floor.

Comment: Yes, as they found out in a nuclear plant fire at one point. Pro tip: spray foam *isn't* non-flammable, it's nearly explosive.

Comment: @FreeMan Is that something I really should be adding around any conduit?

Comment: I can't quote you chapter & verse, but I'm pretty sure that fire blocking putty is required by code.

Comment: Fire retardant spray foam is a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bend the conduit,  either use flexible conduit, or use a conduit bender to bend rigid conduit, or use heat to soften rigid PVC conduit.

Comment: Thank you, I don't have a bender, so I'll look into the flexible option. To make sure I understand, you're implying it should be all one continuous piece from the run in the wall (top picture), through the bottom wood and curving into the house (bottom picture)?

Comment: you can use multiple pieces with straight joints between them

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using flexible conduit. It was really easy to get through the angled hole.